# Why did my webcam stop working out of the blue?

Tags: webcam

I have a Logitech C270 HD Webcam and Ubuntu 20.04.2. When I tried to use it today, it didn't work. I tried cheese and zoom but both of them said that they can't detect my camera. When I typed in lsusb in the terminal though, it was detected by the system. I tried restarting, switching USB ports and it still didn't work.

Also, the camera worked fine a few days ago in Ubuntu and it works fine in Windows (on the same system). What could be causing that? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did your system do an update from the last time it worked to today?

Comment: No it didn't. Although it did find an update but I just clicked "Remind me Later"

Comment: OK one reason this can happen is a kernel update from 5.4 to 5.8 The answer is to reboot and from Ubuntu options in grub menu tell it to load the 5.4 kernel.

Comment: All of the options are about loading kernel 5.8

Comment: There should be one to run with an older kernel.

Comment: When I go in "Ubuntu Options" I see ubuntu 5.8.0-44-generic and it's recovery mode and ubuntu 5.8.0-43-generic and it's recovery mode.

Comment: Look at this question it may help, https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version#:~:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20display,the%20SHIFT%20button%20while%20booting.&text=is%20not%20useful-,Show%20activity%20on%20this%20post.,select%20an%20older%20kernel%20version.

Comment: Ok, I've read it and I installed the older kernel (5.4) but it doesn't work. It always freezes when "dev/sda5 clean, 218600/3033296 files, 6046563/12131072 blocks" comes on the screen. Recovery mode doesn't work either.

Comment: That is new info sounds like you have a hardware problem drive going bad.

Comment: Really? But SMART doesn't report anything. Also, I haven't noticed any symptoms of my SSD going bad. Also, I should mention that when I'm booting with the newest kernel it boots up fine, it's just kernel 5.4 that doesn't work.

Comment: SMART is not the only measure of a hard drives performance its going bad. You say it has a problem with freezing on drive check. It always freezes when "dev/sda5 clean, 218600/3033296 files, 6046563/12131072 blocks"

Comment: Well, what can I do now?

Comment: Replace the drive that holds sda5

Comment: Ok, what should I do with the webcam problem? Is there another solution for my webcam?

Comment: Until the HDD problem is solved I would not even think about it.

Comment: I understand the risks and I would like a solution to my problem please. But the reason of my problem may also be because I just went in the terminal and installed the older kernel with apt install

Comment: That does not work and messes up the whole system time to reinstall from fresh.

Comment: So I probably messed up the installation? If yes, I'm lucky that the newer kernel still works. If that's the cause, I'll install the kernel properly.

Comment: Too late reinstall.

Comment: Can't I just delete the improperly installed kernel? I mean, Ubuntu still boots up with the newer kernel.